# React error: No routes matched location "/"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My React app is giving me the error `No routes matched location "/"`

My App.js looks like:

```
import Form from './components/Form';
import NavMenu from './components/NavMenu';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  // Irrelevant code
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <NavMenu />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any thoughts why this is happening?

I got rid of the error, although it's not a clean solution. I created a new component Home.js, added it to App.js with a route of "/" :

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
      <NavMenu response={response}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />}></Route> // Added home element
        <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form response={response} />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Although I'm not a big fan of this solution because Home.js returns null. I just created it to get rid of this warning. What can someone do if they don't actually need a route with a path matching / ?

Comment: You don't have a route with `path` matching `/`

Comment: Do you only need the one route with the one `Form` component? What would any "default" `nav_string` route param value be?

Comment: Does adding a route for "/" solves your problem? @BaselIsmail

Comment: @DanteDX It gets rid of the error.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes.

Comment: @DrewReese This app fetches data from a DynamoDB table, and assigns nav_string a value from this data. The goal is to access a specific item in the DynamoDB table using the route param nav_string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't really need to render anything on the `"/"` path you could render a redirect to the form's route, perhaps with some default value.

Example:

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
      <NavMenu response={response} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/someDefaultValue" replace />} />
        <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form response={response} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

An alternative could also be to render the `Form` component on both routes. RRD is optimized such that the `Form` component remains mounted while navigating between the routes or while the `nav_string` param value changes.

Example:

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
      <NavMenu response={response} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Form response={response} />} />
        <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form response={response} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Just make sure that `Form` can handle a potentially undefined `nav_string` param value. You could provide a fallback value.

```
const { nav_string = "someDefaultValue" } = useParams();
```

And then there is always the "catch all" route where you can render some fallback UI for any "unhandled" routes. This would include `"/"`.

Example:

```
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
      <NavMenu response={response} />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form response={response} />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add 404 route

Page not found will be displayed when no route matches the url

```js
return (
  <Router>
    <div className="content">
      <NavMenu response={response}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/:nav_string" element={<Form response={response} />}></Route>
        <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} /> {/* You can change NotFound element*/}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the format for `"/:nav_string"` is a path parameter, there is no `"/"` path
try type in for example `"/Product"`, then it solved

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
<BrowserRouter>
 <NavMenu/>
   <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Form/>}></Route>
   <Routes/>
<BrowserRouter/>
```